# Javascript TypeError: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript on Codecademy, and I am trying to create a function that tells me the perimeter of a rectangle. The error that has come up is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

My code is:

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
};
  this.calcArea = function() {
      return this.height * this.width;
  };
  // put our perimeter function here!
  this.calcPerimeter = function() {
      return this.height * 2 + this.width * 2;
  };
var rex = new Rectangle(7,3);
var area = rex.calcArea();
var perimeter = rex.calcPerimeter();
```

Any help/advice greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Why is your question title an error message that doesn't match the one in the question? What error are you actually getting?

Comment: "`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`"

Answer (score 1):

`this.calcarea` and `this.calcperimeter` is outside of the scope of the Rectangle. You need them to be inside the brackets of the Rectangle-object to be member-functions. Like so:

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;

  this.calcArea = function() {
      return this.height * this.width;
  }
  // put our perimeter function here!
  this.calcPerimeter = function() {
      return this.height * 2 + this.width * 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have close Rectangle class at wrong place.

Problem with your code is that `calcPerimeter` and `calcArea` is outside `Rectangle` class. So when you perform `rex.calcArea();` the function in undefined.

Use

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    //}; removed from here
    this.calcArea = function () {
        return this.height * this.width;
    };
    this.calcPerimeter = function () {
        return this.height * 2 + this.width * 2;
    };
}; //Place closing brace here

var rex = new Rectangle(7, 3);
var area = rex.calcArea();
var perimeter = rex.calcPerimeter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll Need To use

`Rectangle.prototype`, as follows:

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}
Rectangle.prototype.calcArea = function() {
      return this.height * this.width;
};
Rectangle.prototype.calcPerimeter = function() {
      return this.height * 2 + this.width * 2;
  };
var rex = new Rectangle(7,3);
var area = rex.calcArea();
var perimeter = rex.calcPerimeter();
```

That'll create a `Method` for class `Rectangle`.

In your code Your Methods `area()` and `perimeter` are referring to `this` object, which in this case is pointing to `window`. So it is of no use. To make `this` point to `Rectangles` Object. You need to use `Rectangle.prototype.methodName=function(){//Here this =Rectangle Obj };`

```
className.prototype.methodName
```

in javascript creates `public` methods(methodName) which can be accessible by the `objects` of that class.

[***`DEMO`***](http://jsfiddle.net/Wdkbm/1/).

Hope it Helps! :)!