# Mysterious "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I'm pulling my hair out trying to resolve this error.  This is causing a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`:

```
trange[abs][i] = BENTON(e1, z1, pa1, pI_pot, pz2, pa2);
```

Here's my function:

```
function BENTON(e1f, z1f, a1f, I_potf, z2f, a2f) {
  //my stuff
  BENTON_return = ((a1f / TAU) / (z1f * z1f)) * (prnglo[q] + bzz * cz[n]);
  return BENTON_return;
}
```

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509796/javascript-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function), which didn't shed any light on this issue.  I know variations of this question have been asked before, but I'm hoping the generic instance of this error will be of some use to others that are also learning JS.  Any input will be appreciated.

---

### Update

In the interest of clarity, here is some code that will hopefully put this problem in better context:

```
function Dreamweaver() {
  "use strict";
  ...
  trange = new Array(1);
  for (i = 0; i < trange.length; i = i + 1) {
    trange[i] = new Array(MAXE);//create a new 2-D array
  }
  ...
  i = 0;
  do {
    e1 = tenerg[i];
    trange[abs][i] = BENTON(e1, z1, pa1, pI_pot, pz2, pa2);
    i = i + 1;
  } while (tenerg[i] < 8.0);
  ...
}

function BENTON(e1f, z1f, a1f, I_potf, z2f, a2f) {
  "use strict";
  ...
  //a lot of mathematics
  bzz = (31.8 + 3.86 * Math.exp((5.0 / 8.0) * logi)) * (a2f / z2f) * 1.0E-06 * Math.exp((8.0 / 3.0) * Math.log(z1f));
  BENTON_return = ((a1f / TAU) / (z1f * z1f)) * (prnglo[q] + bzz * cz[n]);
  return BENTON_return;
}
```

JSLint responds with the complaint that `'BENTON' was used before it was defined`.  I've done this kind of thing successfully before, where I constructed the JS equivalent of a subroutine.  Here I'm wanting to employ functions that return single values.  I know it's probably a small error, but I just don't see what I'm doing wrong.  Any feedback would be great.

Comment: *Where* is that function declared? It doesn't seem to be in scope. Please show a complete example.

Comment: Is `BENTON` within the current scope when you're calling it?

Comment: Since this is an execution error we will need a demo, for instance we have no idea whether half those variables like prnglo, cz, TAU etc are defined..

Comment: If `BENTON()` is in the scope, there's probably a syntax error in it, which has prevented the function being parsed.

Comment: Edited original post with code that will hopefully clarify the issue.

Comment: You are using `"use strict"` but you are not actually making your code strict. You can all kinds of undefined variables (e.g. `trange`, `i`). Post code that *actually demonstrates the problem*.

Comment: This is the code that _actually demonstrates the problem_. JSHint and JSLint come up clean with the exception of the aforementioned error.  So yes, I'm being strict.  It is a very long script, so I've posted only the relevant portions.

Comment: You should stop using global variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve these issues I have procedures that behave like **functions** pass a single-valued array that is overwritten for each subsequent call.  So the call goes from:

```
trange[i] = BENTON(e1, z1, pa1, pI_pot, pz2, pa2);
```

...to...

```
BENTON(e1, z1, pa1, pI_pot, pz2, pa2, reichweite);
trange[i] = reichweite[0];
```

My function goes from:

```
function BENTON(e1f, z1f, a1f, I_potf, z2f, a2f) {
  //my stuff
  BENTON = ((a1f / TAU) / (z1f * z1f)) * (prnglo[q] + bzz * cz[n]);
  return BENTON;
}
```

...to...

```
function BENTON(e1f, z1f, a1f, I_potf, z2f, a2f, reichweite) {
  //my stuff
  reichweite[0] = ((a1f / TAU) / (z1f * z1f)) * (prnglo[q] + bzz * cz[n]);
  return reichweite;
}
```

On the other hand, for procedures that behave like **subroutines** I pass a multi-valued array `[]` that is actively populated and not overwritten.

Hopefully this will help those that are new JS.